# How to use JS Babel API with multiple files

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I am trying to concatenate and transpile a bunch of js files using the Node API. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
concat(
    ['my.js', 'source.js', 'files.js'],
    'myCombinedFile.js'
);
let {code,map,ast} = babel.transformFileSync('myCombinedFile.js', {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', 'minify'],
    sourceMaps: 'both'
});
fs.writeFileSync('finalFile.js', code);
```

However, this approach has a problem: the source maps generated by Babel are based on the combined file, not the original source files, so they are practically useless.

I know it's possible to specify multiple files in the Command-Line Interface, but I cannot find any way with the JS API.

My question is: How to I use Bable's JS API so that the source maps point back to the original files?

Comment: Generally you'd want to use a bundler like Webpack. Have you looked into that? Babel only works on individual files, and generally assumes that they are modular code, so concatenation is rarely a good idea.

Comment: We tried using webpack but our JS files don't have import/export (they are plain javascript) so webpack cannot determine dependencies and combine in proper order.

Comment: You could use `gulp-concat` and such, but be aware that you 100% need to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-iife-wrap if you're concatenating Babel files, because Babel creates file-level variables that it assumes won't be globals. Simple concatenation would break that assumption.

Comment: So you're saying Babel each file with iife then pipe to gulp-concat? Will this maintain the inline source maps back to the original source files?

Comment: Using Gulp's general infrastructure for sourcemaps and such, yes: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps and https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat-sourcemap